# How to call parsley methods on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have a multi-step form and currently using parsley for validation. Validation is performed on form elements when the next button is clicked. For some weird reason, validating radio buttons has turned out to be a huge problem.

JS

```
const firstName = $("#pi_fname").parsley();
firstName.isValid() // returns true or false depending on validation rules

const question1 = $("input[type='radio'][name='question1']").parsley();
question1.isValid() // produces Uncaught TypeError: question1.isValid is not a function
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12">            
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="exampleRadios11" value="1"
                  data-required="true">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios11">
                  Strongly disagree
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="exampleRadios12" value="2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios12">
                  Disagree
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="exampleRadios13" value="3">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios13">
                  Neutral
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="exampleRadios14" value="4">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios14">
                  Agree
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="question1" id="exampleRadios15" value="5">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios15">
                  Strongly agree
                </label>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Parsley's documentation says

> When doing $('#target').parsley() or new Parsley('#target'); on a
>    element (or , ), it will bind
>   the field and return a ParsleyField instance. Except for input types
>   radio and checkbox that **don't** have a name attribute or a
>   data-parsley-multiple attribute, they won't be bound (ignored) and
>   will eventually raise a warning in the console.

But the radio buttons have a name attribute. So why is it failing? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

`$("input[type='radio'][name='question1']")` returns a jQuery set with multiple elements. Calling `.parsley()` on it will return an array of Parsley objects and not a Parsley element like you are expecting.

You should call `.first().parsley().isValid()`, or `.parsley()[0].isValid()`. There's nothing special about the first element of course, the result of `isValid` will be the same for any of the radios.